# How can i use value from input to console.log a value from an object?

Tags: javascript, object

I have an object that contains all the months:

```
const months = {
        "january": 31,
        etc...
```

Then i have a text input. I select the value from the input with javascript (.value) in a variabel called "value".

When I type "january" (without quote marks) in the text input and try doing **console.log(months.value);** nothing happens.

How can I convert the value a datatype (or something else) that can be used to select "january" in the object "months"?

Comment: you need to handle an event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A string is fine to select an item from an object, but you should use square bracket notation when you want to get your key name from a variable:

```
console.log(months[value])
```

Comment: Ah, I had tried months[0].value... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand you need this `months[“january”]`
Or `months[value]`

Comment: yup, months[value]. Thanks